# antlr: how not to take prefix of a word as part of token

Tags: antlr4

I would like to have antlr recognize  this pattern

```
int A.B.C.
```

the '.' in A.B.C. shall be optional and there could be spaces within A.B.C., so I came up with this grammar (simplified to show the problem):

```
grammar Test;

root: INT abcLabel intAlpha? ;

intAlpha: INT | INT_ALPHA;

abcLabel:       ABC;

ABC:            A PERIOD? WS? B PERIOD? WS? C PERIOD?;

INT_ALPHA: INT ALPHA;

ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
INT: DIGIT+;
DIGIT: [0-9];
PERIOD: '.';

fragment A: [aA];
fragment B: [bB];
fragment C: [cC];

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

This works fine for "12 A.B. C 23" as expected, but unfortunately, it also works for "12 A.B. Car 23" which is unexpected. It is recognized as "12 A.B. C", dropping "ar 23" at the end. Now I expect partial match to work, so recognizing "12 A.B. C anything afterwards" is desired, but I don't want a whole word like "Car" get split. Is there a way around? Thanks

Comment: I ended up doing a post parsing validation, to make sure the last char I get is not part of remaining words. basically, if last char in the recognized string is not the end of string, check and make sure last char and the char following that are not both letters

Comment: Try makeing A,B and C not fragments, which will cause the ALPHA rule to kick in instead when there's input starting with one of the 3 letters and continues with additional letters (greedy principle).